# The rows come out of the jumbotron

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, layout, bootstrap-4

I'm a bit new using Bootstrap and I'm having a problem with the jumbotron, div class row surpasses the left edge of the jumbotron

This is a sample of how i'm doing it

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid mt-2 pt-4">
        
    <div class="row">
      <h4>Simple Title</h4>      
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <p class="lead">El transformador se encuentra <span class="badge badge-success">APROBADO</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <p class="small">Last revision: 12-11-2018</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

why the text exceeds the edge of the jumbotron? 
what am i doing wrong?

Edit: [codepen](https://codepen.io/juan-salvador-portugal/pen/LXbbEd?editors=1000) to see the problem in diferent resolution

Thanks

Comment: it's because of `.row` class, it's added margin left and right -15px in css, just remove the `.row` class

Comment: @ManishPatel hi, thanks, i know the problem its caused because of row class, the thing is the layout of my jumbotron are a little complex so i need that functionality did exist some way to use it?

Comment: it's important to add row class?

Comment: I'm using to use the layout, if i want to jump to new row should i replace it for `col-**-12` instead?

Comment: just remove `jumbotron-fluid` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `jumbotron-fluid` class

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-2 pt-4">
        
    <div class="row">
        <h4>Simple Title</h4> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <p class="lead">El transformador se encuentra <span class="badge badge-success">APROBADO</span></p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <p class="small">Last revision: 12-11-2018</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty! that was exactly the solution, do you know why `jumbotron-fluid` was provoking the issue?

Comment: In css padding right and left equal to 0 in `jumbotron-fluid` class.. so that it not getting space in left and right side..